# Docker MySQL Host Volume

Tags: mysql, docker, volume

I found that there is an official MySQL image for docker [here](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/mysql/). Unfortunately, I am unable to start the container with a host volume. I have tried the following script.

```
DB_ROOT_PASS="myPassword"
DB_NAME="myDatabase"
DATA_DIR="$HOME/mysql_data"

mkdir -p $DATA_DIR
mkdir -p $DATA_DIR/conf.d

cd $DATA_DIR
wget -O my.cnf http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=aV4pXRQD

sudo docker run \
-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$DB_ROOT_PASS \
-e MYSQL_DATABASE=$DB_NAME \
-p 3306:3306 \
-v $DATA_DIR:/etc/mysql \
mysql
```

which results in the following output:

```
Running mysql_install_db ...
Installing MySQL system tables...2015-02-14 07:49:52 0 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
2015-02-14 07:49:52 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
OK

Filling help tables...2015-02-14 07:49:55 0 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
2015-02-14 07:49:55 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
OK

To start mysqld at boot time you have to copy
support-files/mysql.server to the right place for your system

PLEASE REMEMBER TO SET A PASSWORD FOR THE MySQL root USER !
To do so, start the server, then issue the following commands:

  /usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'new-password'
  /usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root -h 2efc65e86051 password 'new-password'

Alternatively you can run:

  /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation

which will also give you the option of removing the test
databases and anonymous user created by default.  This is
strongly recommended for production servers.

See the manual for more instructions.

You can start the MySQL daemon with:

  cd /usr ; /usr/bin/mysqld_safe &

You can test the MySQL daemon with mysql-test-run.pl

  cd mysql-test ; perl mysql-test-run.pl

Please report any problems at http://bugs.mysql.com/

The latest information about MySQL is available on the web at

  http://www.mysql.com

Support MySQL by buying support/licenses at http://shop.mysql.com

WARNING: Found existing config file /usr/my.cnf on the system.
Because this file might be in use, it was not replaced,
but was used in bootstrap (unless you used --defaults-file)
and when you later start the server.
The new default config file was created as /usr/my-new.cnf,
please compare it with your file and take the changes you need.

WARNING: Default config file /etc/mysql/my.cnf exists on the system
This file will be read by default by the MySQL server
If you do not want to use this, either remove it, or use the
--defaults-file argument to mysqld_safe when starting the server

Finished mysql_install_db
2015-02-14 07:49:57 0 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
2015-02-14 07:49:57 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
```

I have also tried without creating the `conf.d` directory or the `my.cnf` files which also result in other errors.

#### Why is a volume necessary?

A host volume provides "near metal" disk performance as well as data persistance which is important with a MySQL database. Thus backing up the data from the container, or using the "data container" pattern is not desired.

#### Question:

How can I update the script in order to start the Docker MySQL container with a host volume such that the MySQL service starts correctly? Perhaps passing an init script or adding more data to the volume?

#### Context

- Ubuntu 14.04 64bit server
- Docker version 1.5.0, build a8a31ef

Comment: I see that someone has marked down the question and pushed for it to be closed. Would they care to explain why?

Comment: I don't see any errors. What do you expect to happen that isn't happening?

Comment: @Adrian for me, the container is running but I cannot connect to the mysql service, and `service mysql status` outputs `MySQL Community Server 5.6.23 is not running.`

Comment: realized that updating the my.cnf file to comment out the bind-address allowed me to connect from outside the host. I also realize now that I need another volume for the data_dir and the scripts data_dir is actually the configuration directory. Will post when I have a finalized working solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were several problems, the primary one being that the original config file that was being downloaded had a `bind-address` setting that resulted in the mysql service not being able to be connected to from outside the host. I have since updated the setting (commented it out) and gotten the service running correctly, yet `service mysql status` still states `MySQL Community Server 5.6.23 is not running.` even though it is. I am 99% sure this is because of the "containerization" effect.

Also, the data is not kept at `/etc/mysql`, so to achieve persistence and higher performance, we need to add another volume. The finalized working script is as such:

```
DB_ROOT_PASS="myPassword"
DB_NAME="myDatabase"
CONFIG_DIR="$HOME/mysql_config"
DATA_DIR="$HOME/mysql_data"

mkdir -p $DATA_DIR
mkdir -p $CONFIG_DIR
mkdir -p $CONFIG_DIR/conf.d

cd $CONFIG_DIR
sudo wget -O my.cnf http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=aV4pXRQD

sudo docker run \
-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$DB_ROOT_PASS \
-e MYSQL_DATABASE=$DB_NAME \
-p 3306:3306 \
-v $CONFIG_DIR:/etc/mysql \
-v $DATA_DIR:/var/lib/mysql \
-d \
mysql
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are seeing the message

```
MySQL Community Server 5.6.23 is not running.
```

is because the command `ps` is not loaded in this container. The `service mysql status` command (and all of the service status commands) depend on ps to check status.

When I run `service mysql status` the full message I get is:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql: line 41: ps: command not found
MySQL Community Server 5.6.23 is not running.
```

And indeed if I try running ps directly I get

```
bash: ps: command not found
```

Not certain why they did not provide ps in this container, might be worth opening an issue on it.

Comment: to install ps: `apt-get update && apt-get install -y procps`